# How to sort an array by date in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I need to sort this 2D array in order of the dates in each element. I have tried every other solution on the website and none seem to work.

```py
lst=[['08/12/2020,gggggh,medium'], 
     ['17/12/2020,hhhhhhh,medium'], 
     ['09/12/2020,bbbbbb,low'], 
     ['30/12/2020,bbbbbb,low']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try extract the date from string then sort.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Since you've tried everything on this site, then you have code to post.  Until you do so, you do not have a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you really tried every other solution on this website, but here's how you can do in a fool-proof way:

```py
from datetime import datetime

lst=[['08/12/2020,gggggh,medium'], 
     ['17/12/2020,hhhhhhh,medium'], 
     ['09/12/2020,bbbbbb,low'], 
     ['30/12/2020,bbbbbb,low']]

lst.sort(key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0].split(',')[0], "%d/%m/%Y"))
# Your list `lst` is sorted now.
print(lst)
```

Outputs

> ```
> [['08/12/2020,gggggh,medium'],
> ['09/12/2020,bbbbbb,low'],
> ['17/12/2020,hhhhhhh,medium'],
> ['30/12/2020,bbbbbb,low']]
> ```

Update: It might be helpful for you to also check this official documentation out regarding the [date-time formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) that I used in the above code.

Comment: i tried this exact solution earlier. Let me post the error

Comment: Oh wait! it actually worked this time. The previous version i tried didnt have the 'from datetime import datetime' line

Answer (score 0):

First, I voted for Daveldito’s answer because it was correct. The only thing I’d do differently is to pull the date code out into a function so that it’s more readable (and more importantly, testable!), like so:

```
def by_date(item):
    date = item.split(“,”)[0]
    return datetime.strptime(date, “%d/%m/%Y”)

def test_by_date():
    assert by_date(“08/12/2020,gggggh,medium”) == datetime(2020, 12, 8, 0, 0)

lst.sort(key=by_date)
```

The logic is exactly the same, but I feel this version is more readable when things break at 3AM and I have to wake up and fix them. Also, see how easy it is to write unit tests to validate that you’re sorting on the value that you think you are?

But still, this is just a variant on Daveldito’s correct (and good) answer.